# Escribir archivo txt con salto de linea

Tags: javascript, java

Intento escribir un archivo txt, sin embargo el documento lo escribe sin saltos de linea.

Este es el método el cual recibe una matriz de datos:

```
private void guardarArchivo(ArrayList<String[]> matriz) {
        String[] fila = null;
        String linea;
        try {
            String nombre = "";
            JFileChooser file = new JFileChooser();
            file.showSaveDialog(this);
            File guarda = file.getSelectedFile();
            FileWriter save = new FileWriter(guarda + ".txt");
            if (guarda != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < matriz.size(); i++) {
                    fila = matriz.get(i);
                    linea = "";
                    for (int j = 0; j < fila.length; j++) {
                        if (j == 9) {
                            linea += right(linea.concat(" " + fila[j] + "|"), 8);
                        } else {
                            linea = linea.concat(fila[j] + "|");
                        }
                    }
                    save.write(linea);                   
                }
                save.close();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El archivo se a guardado Exitosamente", "Información", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Su archivo no se ha guardado", "Advertencia", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Has probado usar "\n"?

Comment: Hola @AndySamuelAlvarado, si ya lo probé de estas dos manera  **save.write(linea+"\n");** y **save.write(linea); save.write("\n");** al momento de escribir.

Comment: ya lo arregle, de esta manera **save.write(linea+"\r\n");**, Gracias @AndySamuelAlvarado

Answer (score -2):

Intenta escribiéndolo en etiquetas de HTML antes de imprimirlo en pantalla, puedes usar un simple párrafo para ello.

`<p>texto...</p>` y dar saltos de linea con `<br>`

Comment: Eso sólo funcionaría en un navegador, lo que quiere el usuario es añadir saltos de línea reales